# Concat user input onto a str in C

Tags: c, char, concatenation

I am writing a program where I need to get user input of a program name and up to 2 parameters and then execute the said program. My issue is dealing with taking user input and concating it to a string of "./" as the program is going to execute from the given directory. What I have so far tried to work with is this.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])){
    int counter = 0;
    char input[80];
    char ProgramName[80];
    printf("Enter program name and any parameters: ");
    fgets(input, 80, stdin);
    while(!isspace(input[counter])){
        ProgramName[counter] = input[counter];
        counter++;
    }
}
```

I use isspace to check for white space, and when I encounter it, I know that a paramter follows and that is the end of the program name. My issue is, how do I concat the name of the program to ./ without any extra trailing blank characters or anything that will not cause it to execute correctly? I tried using strcpy and strcat, but I get a bunch of weird trailing characters in the command window when I do that.

Comment: fscanf seems appropriate for C

Comment: `scanf` is never appropriate.

Comment: At what point in the above program do you expect to add the `./`? As a matter of fact, that string does not occur *anywhere* in the code you've shown. Otherwise, it doesn't look completely wrong.

Comment: Also note that you don't actually have to copy for this. You can leave two characters empty at the beginning of the buffer, read the input, put `'/'` before the first non-white-space character and `'.'` before that. Then you replace spaces with `'\0'` while recording pointers to the beginning of non-white-space sequences.

Comment: Leading question: what happens if the user enters a string without a space? Will the `while` loop terminate?

Comment: I did what 5gon12eder suggested and it is working just fine, I think I tried to over complicate what I was shooting for. Also I didn't post the rest of the code where I ran into issues as it was incorrect, I just posted what I knew I wanted to work with and was looking for ways to implement my stated goals. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Also, the while loop currently terminates at the end of the array when I compile, but that is not a good way for me to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably seeing trailing garbage because `ProgramName` isn't a string: It's missing a NUL terminator. You could fix that by adding

```
ProgramName[counter] = '\0';
```

after the loop.

To prepend `./` to the string, why not do that at the beginning?

```
int counter_a = 0, counter_b = 0;
...
ProgramName[counter_a++] = '.';
ProgramName[counter_a++] = '/';
while (!isspace(input[counter_b])) {
    ProgramName[counter_a++] = input[counter_b++];
}
ProgramName[counter_a] = '\0';
```

---

Finally, passing a `char` to `isspace` is wrong because `isspace` is only defined on non-negative inputs but `char` can be negative. You can fix that with:

```
while (input[counter] != '\0' && !isspace((unsigned char)input[counter])) {
```

I also added the check for `'\0'` above. This is necessary to not read past the end of `input` if it doesn't contain any spaces.